# Pepper falsely claims there are no coins left in Turbine Town

Tags: here-comes-niko

The whiteboard in Turbine Town indicates I've found 10/11 coins in the area. However, when I talk to Pepper for a hint they claim there are no coins left to find.

What coin am I missing in Turbine Town?

[image: 10/11 coins collected]

[image: Pepper falsely claims there are no coins left]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My missing coin was from talking to Mai near the red torii gates and trading 5 cassettes for a coin.

[image: Mai trading 5 cassettes for a coin]